Error menu in blender

When I try to extrude some faces, why don't the extrusion options appear in the menu when I click?

They should appear if you click and hold the mouse button down on the icon. You can also use ALT-E to bring up the menu or use the Face menu on the top toolbar.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Gracias por la recomendación, además, en blender al darle ALT+E me sale solo una opción, pero al mantenerle oprimido por un rato si ya funciona, disculpen la novatada soy nuevo.
